# Unit of work with .Net Core registered in Autofac throws System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, autofac, unit-of-work

I tried in scope of one HttpRequest call through Unit of Work my repository twice, but in second time I have got an System.ObjectDisposedException exception. Can anybody help me?

My DBContext

```
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public SwapDealContext(IConfigurationManager configurationManager)
        : base()
    {
        this.connectionString = configurationManager.DbConnectionString;
    }

    public SwapDealContext(DbContextOptions<SwapDealContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.connectionString);
        }
    }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

AutoFac Module:

```
public class DataAccessAutoFacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        Assembly assembly = typeof(DataAccessAutoFacModule).Assembly;
        base.Load(builder);
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWorkFactory>().As<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Interfaces:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork();
}
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{        
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

    T GetRepository<T>()
        where T : class;
}
```

Implemantations:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> repositories;
    private readonly ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope;

    public UnitOfWork(
        DbContext dbContext,
        ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
        this.repositories = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }        

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.dbContext.Dispose();
        this.repositories.Clear();
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        try
        {
            int changes = await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            return changes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw;
        }
    }        

    public T GetRepository<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        var typeName = typeof(T).Name;

        if (!this.repositories.ContainsKey(typeName))
        {
            T instance = this.lifetimeScope.Resolve<T>(new TypedParameter(typeof(DbContext), this.dbContext));
            this.repositories.Add(typeName, instance);
        }

        return (T)this.repositories[typeName];
    }
}
public class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope;
    private readonly SwapDealContext context;

    public UnitOfWorkFactory(
        SwapDealContext context,
        ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    public IUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork()
    {
        return new UnitOfWork(this.context, this.lifetimeScope);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
    public async Task<IList<UserDetails>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        using (var uow = this.unitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
        {
            var userRepo = uow.GetRepository<IUserRepository>();

            var result = await userRepo.GetAllUsers();

            return Mapper.Map<List<UserDetails>>(result);
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    public UserController(IUserService userService, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("users")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IList<UserDetails>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersAnync()
    {
        try
        {
            var users = await userService.GetAllUsers();
            var users2 = await userService.GetAllUsers();

            if (!users.Any())
            {
                return NotFound($"No one user were found");
            }

            return Ok(users);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.ErrorFormat("Could not get users due to: {0}", ex, ex.Message);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

}

StackTrace:

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.IDbContextDependencies.get_QueryProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor..ctor(IEvaluatableExpressionFilter evaluatableExpressionFilter, IParameterValues parameterValues, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, DbContext context, Boolean parameterize, Boolean generateContextAccessors)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryModelGenerator.ExtractParameters(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Expression query, IParameterValues parameterValues, Boolean parameterize, Boolean generateContextAccessors)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IncludableQueryable`2.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SwapDeal.DataAccess.Repositories.UserRepository.GetAllUsers() in C:\Users\osmachenko\personal\VAO\SwapDeal.DataAccess\Repositories\UserRepository.cs:line 23
   at SwapDeal.BizLogic.Services.UserService.GetAllUsers() in C:\Users\osmachenko\personal\VAO\SwapDeal.BizLogic\Services\UserService.cs:line 40
   at SwapDeal.WebApi.Controllers.UserController.GetUsersAnync() in C:\Users\osmachenko\personal\VAO\SwapDeal.WebApi\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 37
```

So, when I call GetAllUsers method twice in Controller I have got System.ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: Add the stack trace to your question. That should give clues as to which object is disposed.

Comment: dbContext in UnitOfWork class is disposed, next time when call service from controller and dbContext is already disposed

Comment: When I mentioned you should add the stack trace to your question... _Add the stack trace to your question._ Probably also include the code that calls the "GetAllUsers" method twice. Not trying to be pedantic, there's just not enough here to go on. The stack trace gives clues about where things are happening - more than just the message.

Comment: added controller and stacktrace as you requested

Comment: Thanks, this helps put it in context and provides much closer to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the context disposed is because you are disposing it.

If we trace through...

- Every type you're registering with Autofac appears to be registered `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. That means you'll get one per lifetime scope. In ASP.NET Core, that equates to one instance per request (basically).
- The controller will get an `IUserService` in its controller. We don't see what the whole `IUserService` looks like, but we do see `GetAllUsers` in the example code.
- `GetAllUsers` wraps the operation in a `using` statement - it creates, *and then disposes* the unit of work when it's done.
- In the constructor of `UnitOfWork` you pass in the `DbContext` - the *one instance* you get that request, and then...
- In `UnitOfWork.Dispose` you dispose of the `DbContext`. That happens at the end of `GetAllUsers` because of that `using` statement.

```cs
    public async Task<IList<UserDetails>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        // The factory creates the unit of work here...
        using (var uow = this.unitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
        {
            var userRepo = uow.GetRepository<IUserRepository>();

            var result = await userRepo.GetAllUsers();

            return Mapper.Map<List<UserDetails>>(result);
            // At the end of this using statement, the unit of work gets disposed
            // and in UnitOfWork.Dispose() you dispose of the DbContext.
        }
    }
```

If you want to call the operation twice, you either need to:

- Not dispose of the context at the end of the unit of work; **OR**
- Provide every unit of work with its own database context.

Comment: The main problem was to create a new db context for every unit of work and also to summarise all repositories and services use DbContext and register it as InstancePerLifetimeScope. Thank you for your help!